# c# regex pattern position and last 3 chars

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a new string based on a file name. Part of the name contains irrelevant information like the current year.  For example `D2015987.txt`. For me the important part of the regex is to extract `D987` from the part of the file name.

I started off by using `Regex.Match(@"D\d{4}|\d{3}\b+")`, this seems to trim off the last digit when I get the values. In reality I am attempting to create a new string from this value, so I may also be able to use `string newStr = Regex.Replace(pattern).value  ...`

I also need assistance with creating a new value that will match a pattern similar to this `D11Q1987.txt ...` from this I need the `DQ987` part as well.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Dan

Comment: So is the format always like this: 1 symbol that you need, then 4 symbols that you don't need and then another 3 symbols that you need?

Comment: You have to assign meaning to the coded parts, and account for _all_ parts. Otherwise you will not go anywhere with this.

Comment: You need to edit your post, the regex you tried doesn't match the format of the sample. `D\d{4}...` looks for a string that starts with `D<4 digits>` but the only sample you provided gives two digits so is it a variable number of digits between D & Q? Is the first item you want to capture ("D" here) and the second item ("Q" here) always separated only by numbers? The last part you want to extract, is it always 3 digits? Can it be more? If more, is the immediately previous character always a digit? Also `\b+` means <one or more word boundaries>, what's the point of this?

Comment: Yes, I have two styles of document naming that I can receive.  Monthly or Quarterly.  Monthly looks like D2011000.txt and Quarterly looks like D11Q1000.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this :**
pattern is `^(\w)\d+(\d{3})\.txt$`
 replace with `$1$2`

now u use this code in your code according your (C#) syntax. i hope this work.
**c# code**

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // This is the input string we are replacing parts from.
    string input = "D2015987.txt";

    // Use Regex.Replace to replace the pattern in the input.
    string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"^(\w)\d+(\d{3})\.txt$", "$1$2");

    // Write the output.
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

output c#

```
D2015987.txt
D987
```

**another php solution**

```
$str = "D2015987.txt";

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
$r=$matches[1].$matches[2];
var_dump($r );
```

**output for php**

```
string 'D987' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `(.)` grabs the first, capture group 1
2. `\d+` matches any number of digits (but at least one)
3. `([A-Za-z])` matches a single character, and captures it as group 1.
4. `\d` matches a single digit.
5. `(\d{3})` matches three digits.
6. `\.` escapes the period.
7. `txt` finishes it off looking for the literal characters txt

Regex:

```
    (.)\d+([A-Za-z])\d(\d{3})\.txt
```

Now, if the last digits are variable length, but always preceded by a digit, we simply change the `{3}` to `+`.

```
    (.)\d+([A-Za-z])\d(\d+)\.txt
```

`$1` contains D (by your example), `$2' contains Q (by your example) and $3 contains 987, but both examples depend on being preceded by a digit that we can use as a marker but throw away.